# Matching user inputs and calculating the inputs by the number c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My question is to record the user 5 inputs and matching them to the correct code. `singleperson` code is 1, `couple` code is 2 and `family` is 3. Hence the users input will only be these 3 numbers.At the end I must calculate the total of the total number of people by their category. I ran the code and got runtime error saying stack around variable "groups" is corrupted and always have only 5 singles while the couples and families are 0. Sorry, I just started school and I'm a bit blurry..

```
int singleperson=0;
int couple=0;
int family3=0;

int groups[]={0,0,0,0,0};
cout << "Enter group #1:";
cin >>groups[0];
cout << "Enter group #2:";
cin >>groups[1];
cout << "Enter group #3:";
cin >>groups[2];
cout << "Enter group #4:";
cin >>groups[3];
cout << "Enter group #5:";
cin >>groups[4];
for (int a=0; a<=4;a++)
{
    if(groups[a]=1)
    {
        singleperson= singleperson + 1;
    }
    else if(groups[a]=2)
    {
        couple = couple +1;
    }
    else
    {
        family3= family3+1;
    }
}
cout<<"Statistics"<<endl;
cout <<singleperson<<"Singles"<<endl;
cout<<couple<<"Couples"<<endl;
cout<<family3<<"Families"<<endl;
```

Comment: you reserve 4 positions and use 5. The comparison operator is == not =. Anyway, You would improve your level of C ++ faster if you carefully study a book instead of writing all this basic details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because size of `group` is `4` and you are trying to insert into `5th` place. And as pointed by @antonio-garrido to check equality we use `==` and `=` is used for assignment.

```
int groups[]={0,0,0,0,0};


for (int a=0 ; a <= 4; a++) {
    if(groups[a] == 1) {
        singleperson= singleperson + 1;
    } else if(groups[a] == 2) {
        couple = couple +1;
    } else {
        family3= family3+1;
    }
}
```